# How to find the coordinates of the marker google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Tell me, please, how the handler Event marker/cluster google maps (for example events mouseover) to obtain the coordinates of the Marker/cluster on the Browser window?
The documentation says that the OverlayView class contains methods to convert map coordinates to coordinates on the screen. But how to do it I can't understand.
To obtain the screen coordinates of the marker I want to block:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(e) {

    });
```

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you ran into trying to do that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1 marker or multiple markers?  For 1 marker you can use iceblade's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(e) {
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    var lat = pos.lat();
    var lng = pos.lng();
});
```

That should get you the coordinates of the marker.

Comment: I need the coordinates on the screen in pixels, not geographic coordinates.